# How to persist verbose boot flag in Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris

Sun Solaris 10 3/05 accepts a boot parameter `boot -verbose` that boots the system with verbose messages enabled.

How do I persist this setting so that I do not have to type it at boot time ?

Example screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `eeprom` command to set the verbosity of boot output. Exec:

```
eeprom verbosity?=max
```

and reboot the machine to check. Beside `max` you can set `debug` level of verbosity. For more information you may refer [man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E88353_01/html/E72487/eeprom-8.html) of `eeprom`

Comment: My old Solaris 10 3/05 version does not support the `verbosity` parameter. However the workaround is `eeprom boot-args=-v`.